# PHP - isolating element(s) with same key in seemingly complicated array

Tags: php, arrays, key

I have 1 single variable `$input_args` which seems to contain multiple arrays (multidimensional?):

> Array ( [required] => 1 [html_label_text] => What is your gender? [required_validation_error_message] => Please enter your gender [html_name] => ee_reg_qstn[356][17] [html_id] => **ee-reg-qstn [default] =>** **Male** )
>
> Array ( [required] => 1 [html_label_text] => Favorite color? [required_validation_error_message] => Oops! Looks like something is missing [html_name] => ee_reg_qstn[356][12] [html_id] =>  **ee-reg-qstn [default] =>** **Blue** )
>
> Array ( [required] => 1 [html_label_text] => What is your weight? [required_validation_error_message] => Enter your weight [html_name] => ee_reg_qstn[356][18] [html_id] =>  **ee-reg-qstn [default] =>** **144** )

I want to isolate the different values corresponding to the `[default]` key in `$input_args` but I cannot seem to do it. Echoing `$input_args['default']` yields all the values i.e. `MaleBlue144`, but try to select the values individually seem to be setting the value lengths `$input_args['default'][0]` yields `MB1`.

I am a php novice. Thanks in advance for helping!

edit:
this is the exact array(s) upon doing `var_export`

```
array ( 'required' => true, 'html_label_text' => 'What is your gender?', 'required_validation_error_message' => 'Please enter your gender', 'html_name' => 'ee_reg_qstn[376][17]', 'html_id' => 'ee_reg_qstn-376-17', 'html_class' => 'ee-reg-qstn ee-reg-qstn-17', 'html_label_id' => 'ee_reg_qstn-376-17-lbl', 'html_label_class' => 'ee-reg-qstn', 'default' => 'Male', )array ( 'required' => true, 'html_label_text' => 'What is your color?', 'required_validation_error_message' => 'Oops! Looks like something is missing', 'html_name' => 'ee_reg_qstn[376][12]', 'html_id' => 'ee_reg_qstn-376-12', 'html_class' => 'ee-reg-qstn ee-reg-qstn-12', 'html_label_id' => 'ee_reg_qstn-376-12-lbl', 'html_label_class' => 'ee-reg-qstn', 'default' => 'Brown', )array ( 'required' => true, 'html_label_text' => 'What is your weight?', 'required_validation_error_message' => 'Enter the weight you will be', 'html_name' => 'ee_reg_qstn[376][18]', 'html_id' => 'ee_reg_qstn-376-18', 'html_class' => 'ee-reg-qstn ee-reg-qstn-18', 'html_label_id' => 'ee_reg_qstn-376-18-lbl', 'html_label_class' => 'ee-reg-qstn', 'default' => '111', )array ( 'required' => true, 'html_label_text' => 'What is you academy name?', 'required_validation_error_message' => 'If none, type "Independent"', 'html_name' => 'ee_reg_qstn[376][13]', 'html_id' => 'ee_reg_qstn-376-13', 'html_class' => 'ee-reg-qstn ee-reg-qstn-13', 'html_label_id' => 'ee_reg_qstn-376-13-lbl', 'html_label_class' => 'ee-reg-qstn', 'validation_strategies' => array ( 0 => EE_Max_Length_Validation_Strategy::__set_state(array( '_max_length' => INF, '_validation_error_message' => 'Input is too long. Maximum number of characters is INF', '_input' => NULL, )), ), 'default' => 'Inception', )array ( 'required' => true, 'html_label_text' => 'What is your  team name?', 'required_validation_error_message' => 'If none, type "Independent"', 'html_name' => 'ee_reg_qstn[376][14]', 'html_id' => 'ee_reg_qstn-376-14', 'html_class' => 'ee-reg-qstn ee-reg-qstn-14', 'html_label_id' => 'ee_reg_qstn-376-14-lbl', 'html_label_class' => 'ee-reg-qstn', 'validation_strategies' => array ( 0 => EE_Max_Length_Validation_Strategy::__set_state(array( '_max_length' => INF, '_validation_error_message' => 'Input is too long. Maximum number of characters is INF', '_input' => NULL, )), ), 'default' => 'VS All Stars', )array ( 'required' => false, 'html_label_text' => 'I don\'t want to be matched with opposite gender', 'required_validation_error_message' => '', 'html_name' => 'ee_reg_qstn[376][15]', 'html_id' => 'ee_reg_qstn-376-15', 'html_class' => 'ee-reg-qstn ee-reg-qstn-15', 'html_label_id' => 'ee_reg_qstn-376-15-lbl', 'html_label_class' => 'ee-reg-qstn', 'default' => array ( ), )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want all the values from the default key, you might use [array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) and specify default as the column key.

```
print_r(array_column($input_args, "default"));
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => ** **Male**
    [1] => ** **Blue**
    [2] => ** **144**
)
```

If you perhaps have unique data that can form an array key, you might specify a third parameter. For example:

```
array_column($input_args, "default", "html_name")
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/ZfYMp)

Comment: doing `print_r(array_column($input_args, "default"));` is yielding `Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( )` for some reason.

Comment: @machump If you click on the demo, is your array structure like that? ?Can you use `var_export($input_args);` and add that to the question?

Comment: I've appended the exact var_export to the initial post. The first several arrays from the question are actually a subset of several more.

Comment: very interesting.. I guess accept your answer and I'll tinker some more. Thanks!